# Call to Setup Table in WatchKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, watchkit

I have a WatchKit app and can't figure out the best place to **call my function that sets up the `table`** in my `InterfaceController`.

`InterfaceController`:

```
   var receivedData = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

    var eventsListSO = Array<Event>()

    @IBOutlet var rowTable: WKInterfaceTable!

    func doTable() {

        eventsListSO = Event.eventsListFromValues(receivedData)
        rowTable.setNumberOfRows(eventsListSO.count, withRowType: "rows")

        for var i = 0; i < self.rowTable.numberOfRows; i++ {
            let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(i) as? TableRowController
            for eventm in eventsListSO {
                row!.mLabel.setText(eventm.eventMatch)
                NSLog("SetupTableM: %@", eventm.eventMatch)
            }
        }

    }
```

If my `doTable` code looks correct and where to call it in `InterfaceController`?

Comment: When value is assigned  to `receivedData `? You should call `doTable` after value is assigned.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa thanks for the response!  So is that best called in `willActivate`, `awakeWithContext`, or something else?

Comment: It depends. `willActivate` is called several times each time the screen is displayed. `awakeWithContext` is first called only once. See also "Improve load times with fewer table rows."  https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/

Comment: @KosukeOgawa so it looks like from that link, its best to call `doTable` in willActivate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @KosukeOgawa, `willActivate`